# How to destructure an array from inside an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object-destructuring

I have an object like this:

```
obj = {'id': 1, a: [1, 2, 3]}
```

I want to destructure and get the array a from `obj`

```
arr = {...obj.a}
```

I get:

```
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}
```

which is not an array

How to get the array itself ?

Comment: `arr=obj.a` ....

Comment: use brackets: arr = [...obj.a]

Comment: This isn't destructuring, BTW. It's spreading `obj.a` into a new object (i.e. shallow copying). Do you intend to get the original array or create a new one?

Comment: i think he's trying to do `let  {a: arr} = {'id': 1, a: [1, 2, 3]}`

Comment: Or did you mean `{ a: obj.a }` ?

Comment: @p.s.w.g i intended to get the original one. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) an array inside `{}`. This creates an object with indices of the array as keys. This is why you get `{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}`

```js
const a = [ 1, 2 ]

console.log({ ...a })
```

If you want to get a property into a variable, this is the [correct syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const { propertyName } = yourObject
// if you want to have a variable name which is different than the propertyName
const { propertyName: someOtherVariable } = yourObject
```

Here's the working snippet:

```js
const obj = {'id': 1, a: [1, 2, 3] }

const { a: arr } = obj; // this is same as: const arr = obj.a

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: You can rename the `a` to `arr` using `const { a : arr } = obj`

Comment: You could create a shallow copy *and* destructure all at once: `const { a: [...arr] } = obj;`, if that's needed. (OP's requirements aren't all that clear, IMO)

Comment: @p.s.w.g from "*I want to destructure and get the array a from obj*", I'm assuming. OP's got destructuring and spread syntax mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Almost - it's the other way round :)

`let  {a: arr} = {'id': 1, a: [1, 2, 3]}`

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure to an array by assigning the array to an array with a rest syntax.

```js
var obj = { id: 1, a: [1, 2, 3] },
    [...arr] = obj.a;

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets instead of curly braces to [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it into a new array:

```js
const obj = {'id': 1, a: [1, 2, 3]}    
const arr = [...obj.a]
console.log(arr)
```